# Help with intentional instantiation in "The nature and plausibility of Cognitivism"

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, ontology, artificial-intelligence, intentionality, philosophy-of-psychology

When the computer-based chess player is explained [1], the bottom level components of the chess playing heirarchy are intentionally instantiated by list processors.

My question is this, doesn't philosophy of mind suggest that when the components are instantiated as list processors, wouldn't the
overall chess player need to be instantiated as one too?

Fo example, if the chess playing hierarchy is:

1. Chess player (IPS).

   1.1. Move generator (IBB).

   1.2. Move announcer (IBB).

And the 'Move generator' and 'Move announcer' are instantiated by the procedures 'Move generating procedure' and 'Move accouncing procedure':

1. Chess player (IPS) --> ?.

   1.1. Move generator (IBB) --> Move Generating Procedure.

   1.2. Move announcer (IBB) --> Move Announcing Procedure.

shouldn't there be a 'Chess playing procedure' to instantiate the Chess player too?

References:

```
[1] Haugeland, J. (1978). The nature and plausibility of Cognitivism.  Chapter 1 'Having Thought' Page 27
```

Comment: As an aside, you're on the right track. The [PSSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_symbol_system) was a bedrock of belief for the brightest minds in AI for a long time, but most reasonable computer scientists see the necessity of balancing it with [connectionism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectionism). Even Alan Turing in his imitation game concedes that computer intelligence will somehow need to learn like children. There's more to neurological computation than Chomskian grammars and Turing machines!

Comment: I don't know what you think philosophy of mind has to do with it. As an engineering question, the answer is "no". The Chess Player is instantiated as two "list processors" (whatever that means). One of those is the Move Generator and the other is the Announcer (which more properly would be called an Evaluator). None of this has anything to do with philosophy of mind.

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

You're attempting to simulate a chess player. As such, you are rightfully presuming that there are philosophical overtones to doing so. What you ask, however, is a normative question regarding object-oriented design principles including [design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern). As such, there is a certain [is-ought](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is%E2%80%93ought_problem) divide at play in your question. As such, philosophy offers you no prescription for design of AI systems, and like all problem specifications, **the use of a particular software architecture is a function of your design specifications.**

### Long Answer

John Haugeland was a staunch proponent of a [symbolic approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_artificial_intelligence) to AI. In his [*Artifical Intelligence: The Very Idea*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Artificial_Intelligence/zLFSPdIuqKsC?hl=en&gbpv=0), he attempts to lay out specifics of architecture that might lead to human-level intelligence. Today, that discipline is known as [artificial general intelligence (AGI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_general_intelligence). AGI is a speculative branch of computer science, full of rambunctious engineer types trying to push the boundaries to show more and more sophisticated forms of intelligence that approximate human intelligence. One might consider [Ben Goertzel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Goertzel) one of the heirs to those sorts of effort.

Now, originally, you tagged your question as one of [cognitive psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_psychology), presciently because any attempts at designing architectures for greater intelligence would take it's cue from the function of the human mind. Indeed, there are a number of parallels between computers and brains, and the metaphor of computation in psychology goes back at least 50 years. In the philosophy of mind, the [computational theory of mind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_theory_of_mind) holds a great deal of sway over thinkers, and the idea that software can be written to approximate the brain goes back to at least Marvin Minsky and John von Neumann whose final lecture series before dying of cancer from his involvement in nuclear physics was devoted to comparing and contrasting electronic computers with the biological ones we possess.

But what you are asking for presumes that philosophy has settled exactly what intelligence is, how is it functions, and the best way to replicate it. While 2nd-generation [cognitive science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_science) has a lot to say about the parallels, and philosophers of mind draw heavily from the [naturalized epistemology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalized_epistemology) of cognitive science, there are many philosophers, particularly those who don't have a background in computer science, who simply don't believe there are strong parallels and deny that computers have the capacity of [intentionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intentionality). (See [Computers, Artificial Intelligence, and Epistemology (PhilSE)](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/68956/40730).) From a philosophical perspective, if one cannot replicate intentionality, one cannot replicate human-level intelligence, because the former is a [necessary condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency) of the latter.

So, let's address your question directly from a philosophical perspective:

> My question is this, when the components are instantiated as list processors, wouldn't the overall chess player need to be instantiated as one too?

Would one need to write a class 'player' and instantiate objects thereof? Doesn't really make a difference in regards to whether or not you system performs "intelligently". Class definitions and object instantiation are convenient fictions for organizing state and instruction. In other words, on one level, it might seem more credible to simulate a player hoping that such a software object might be closer to humans, but on another level, the [ALU/CU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit) in a von Neumann machine does one thing: execute op codes. Executables are executables are executables in this regard, just like people are made of atoms. But there is a big difference between the two. People are physical objects that can be described by the uncertainties of quantum mechanics, whereas digital computers largely have that uncertainty ironed out of them in their design (though occasionally bugs, like the [Pentium bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug) slip in).

So, whether or not you use a new operator to instantiate a class called "player" has little bearing on whether or not the software functions like an actual player. Much more relevant are questions like, do human brains and intuition function like machine learning? If computer software is deterministic, can it even perform like human intuition? Are there components to player intuition that are emotional and social which might give a player an edge over another?

If your goal is to have a chess system beat a human, then it makes no difference whether you create an use a player class, because the meat and bones of how a computer like [Deep Blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Blue_(chess_computer)) plays chess has more to do about assessment of brute calculations and permutations than it does it's software design pattern. **Chess software runs on algorithms and heuristics at speeds the human brain can no longer rival, and that has nothing to do with some shallow comparison of players and instantiated objects named players.**